# Nativescript Vue Font Icon Size with Image tag

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

How to set the size of font icon when i use Image tag? I tried with app.scss, but the icon is max size. I couldn't find any other documentation.

[nativescript vue fontawesome size with image tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwOVV.png)

The small icons are with Fontawesome 4.7 and button tag. They are ОК. The big icon is with Fontawesome 5 and Image tag.

```
<Image col="3" src.decode="font://&#xf004;" class="fas" stretch="none" />
```

app.scss

```
.fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free Solid", "fa-solid-900";
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 12;
}
```

Comment: Is that iOS tab view? Did you try setting text along with icon? If result is same, can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Thank you, Manoj! It's Android page with RadListView.
Your question about where i use the image tag helped me to find the problem. Css for font-size is ignored if the image tag is used inside <v-template> of <RadListView> . Everywhere else works correctly. I will work without an image tag or look for another size adjustment solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that font icon size with image tag is ignored inside RadListView (Android).

```
<Image  src.decode="font://&#xf004;" class="fas" stretch="none" /> - This is OK
<RadListView for="">
   <v-template>
      <GridLayout columns="auto,*">
         <button col="0"><FormattedString><Span class="fa" :text="'fa-thumbs-o-up' | fonticon" /><Span :text="10" /></FormattedString></button> - This is OK
         <Image col="1" src.decode="font://&#xf004;" class="fas" stretch="none" /> - This didn't work 
      </GridLayout>                     
   </v-template>
</RadListView>
```

app.scss

```
.fa {
    font-family: FontAwesome; //Font Awesome 4.7
 }

.fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free Solid", "fa-solid-900";
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 12;
}
```